# Is there any BSD licensed alternative to Oracle's JVM (windows)?

Tags: java, oracle, jvm

Is there any BSD licensed alternative to Oracle's JVM (for windows)?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no BSD licensed JVM implementations compatible with Java SE/Java EE.

According to [List of Java virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) on Wikipedia there is only two with [BSD-style license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD-style_licence): [Mika VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mika_VM) and [Wonka VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonka_VM) (both Java ME and way outdated)

You may consider using [OpenJDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) ([GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)) or [OpenJ9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) ([Apache License 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License_2.0)/[Eclipse Public License 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License_2.0)).

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenJDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) has a [GNU General Public License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) and is the basis for Oracle's JVM.

You can download the source here http://openjdk.java.net/